# CakePHP making Zip files, getting file 'bytes exhausted' error message?

Tags: php, cakephp, zip

I am working with Files and Folders within CakePHP. Now everything works fine and in the way I want it to. However, when Zipping files, I get the following error message :

```
Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 240047685 bytes)
```

Now zipping smaller files, its fine! I have even done files in size of around 10MB without any issues, however zipping that are larger in size seem to have an issue.

Now I have added the following to my .htaccess file and made a php.ini file as I thought that might be the issue.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 640000000M
php_value post_max_size 640000000M
php_value max_execution_time 30000000
php_value max_input_time 30000000
```

Until I found some posts pointing at the fact that PHP as a 4GB file limit. Well even if that is the case, why does my zip file not do this file (which is only about 245mb).

```
   public function ZippingMyData() {
     $UserStartPath = '/data-files/tmp/';
     $MyFileData = $this->data['ZipData']; //this is the files selected from a form!

      foreach($MyFileData as $DataKey => $DataValue) {
        $files = array($UserStartPath.$DataValue);
        $zipname = 'file.zip';
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name
        $zip->open($zip_name,  ZipArchive::CREATE);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
         $path = $file;
                if(file_exists($path)) {
            $zip->addFromString(basename($path),  file_get_contents($path));  
                } else {
            echo"file does not exist";
            }
        } //End of foreach loop for $files
      } //End of foreach for $myfiledata

      $this->set('ZipName', $zip_name);
      $this->set('ZipFiles', $MyFileData);
      $zip->close();
      copy($zip_name,$UserStartPath.$zip_name);
      unlink($zip_name); //After copy, remove temp file.
      $this->render('/Pages/download');
    } //End of function
```

Any ideas of where I am going wrong? I will state that this is NOT my code, I found bits of it on others posts and changed it to fit my needs for my project!

All help most welcome...

Thanks

Glenn.

Comment: `php_value memory_limit 256M` Also check if there are extensions like Suhosin installed which may apply a limit to the memory usage.

Comment: I am running this inside my own VM, which I have complete control over. I think (from memory) that I only installed the basic PHP5 files. I think this project will be host in a VPS or at lest something I will have control over, which means that if you can think of something else I can install on the server to make sure there are no file limits at all, then please go right ahead! - thanks Glenn

Comment: just added the 'php_value memory_limit 256M' to the top of my php.ini file. It did not work, still gives me the same error message? Any way of running phpinfo from within CakePHP, to see if the php.ini file is working? and where should my file be hosted? Its is the root of the WWW folder, should I move it to the webroot folder of cake? Thanks Glenn.

Comment: You load complete files into memory. In the long term, you'll have to adapt your code and process files in chunks.

Comment: How would, or should I go about doing that? Also if I am doing that, I am guesting here, but could I also add something like a progress bar using Jquery?

Comment: The `php_value ...` code goes into the `.htaccess`, not the `php.ini`!  In the `php.ini` it would be `memory_limit = 256M`.

Comment: Yeah, I already guest that and sorted it, but it did not change anything! It still will not zip my 245mb file!!

Answer (score 1):

I think that `ZipArchive` loads your file in memory, so you have to increase the `memory_limit` parameter in php.ini.
To avoid consuming all the memory of your server and drop performance, if your file is big, a better (but far from be the best) solution should be:

```
 public function ZippingMyData() {
 $UserStartPath = '/data-files/tmp/';
 $MyFileData = $this->data['ZipData']; //this is the files selected from a form!

 foreach($MyFileData as $DataKey => $DataValue) {
    $files = array($UserStartPath.$DataValue);
    $zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name
    // Instead of a foreach you can put all the files in a single command:
    // /usr/bin/zip $UserStartPath$zip_name $files[0] $files[1] and so on
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      $path = $file;
      if(file_exists($path)) {
        exec("/usr/bin/zip $UserStartPath$zip_name basename($path)");  
      } else {
        echo"file does not exist";
      }
    } //End of foreach loop for $files
  } //End of foreach for $myfiledata

  $this->render('/Pages/download');
} //End of function
```

or similar (depends on your server). This solution has only two limits: disk space and zip limitations.
I apologize for the poor quality of my code and for any error.

Comment: I give this a try! I think I see where your going with this, the code you have added is to get the server to run the zip and not PHP! Umm did not think about that, being researching other methods around using code, even things like NodeJS. Many thanks, I will give this a try and let you know. Glenn.

Comment: @GlennCurtis: be careful with pathnames, zip must know where the files are, and probably you need to junk the pathname with the -j option, otherwise unzipping you'll get something like '/data-files/tmp/' as pathname for the unzipped file.

Comment: I have doing some trying with this, my current try is debug(exec("/usr/local/bin/zip/ ".$UserStartPath.$zip_name.$path)); but the debug just throws back an empty array and I have run it without the debug to see if it made the zip, which it did not!! I am not sure if I am doing it right

Comment: @GlennCurtis: before running zip, echo or log the full command, so you can test it by hand.